# Retrieve HTML source from webpage

Tags: http, rust

I am new to Rust and trying out different projects to become more familiar with the language. As the title says I would like to retrieve the html source of a webpage. I am aware of rust-http but I am not sure how to use that library for this purpose

For a more detailed description of what I am trying to do:
Given some url: www.google.com
I would like the underlying HTML source.

I have looked at the Github Documentation of rust-http but the lack of docs have been confusing.

Comment: Why not just give it a try and see if "it fits your needs."

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. you're asking a very general question... and we're not even sure what *would* fit your needs yet. Stack Overflow works best when you have a specific, technical problem that has a correct answer.  We also expect you to have done some research yourself (even just googling)... basically, you're doing the work here (we're not doing it for you), so show us that you have done some :) and also to put everything relevant into your question.

Comment: So please edit your question and add: a description of what a solution would look like (what are your needs precisely, and why does Rust not fit them?). Tell us about the research you've done, and what you've tried and why they didn't help you. Then we can begin to give you advice. But please be aware, S/O is not a general advice service. We help you solve specific, technical problems - and that means you need to precisely state your problem, and what the solution would look like.

Comment: Well that is what I have been trying to do. The lack of documentation has really left me stuck with not really knowing where to start...

Answer (score 0):

(answer moved from an edit to the question)

After playing around/searching more I finally was able to get what I wanted. Here is some code using Hyper that retrieves the source.

```
let req = request::Request::get(hyper::Url::parse("www.google.com").unwrap()).unwrap();
let res = req.start().unwrap()
                     .send().unwrap()
                     .read_to_string().unwrap();

println!("Response: {}", res);
```

Answer (score -3):

What is wrong with using the options built into the browsers to display source code? E.g Chrome and Firefox: right click and select "View Page Source".

Comment: Umm... because he's not just browsing the code.  There are various reasons one would want to retrieve the code and parse it, such as a crawler.